# Using Cesium.js inside Spring MVC project

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-mvc, cesiumjs

I have a project which is built on top of Spring MVC (not Spring boot). I used the Spring Tool Suit(STS). I want to add the functionalities of Cesium.js project to my Spring Project but the problem is Cesium is a Node.JS application.

I do not know how should I reference the Cesium project inside my Spring MVC project.

Comment: Isn't Cesium client-side?

Comment: Yes I read the documentation but it was not clear what to do. I had to improvise so I moved the resource folders to a folder under my resources in Spring MVC project and kept the index of cesium then I changed the links according to spring links and it all worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation but it was not clear what to do.Basically it says you have to move the root folder to your project and then use it but with Spring MVC its a little bit tricky. 
I moved the resource folders to a folder under my resources in Spring MVC project and kept the index of cesium in my views folder, made a route to it in my controller then I changed the links in the index according to spring links and also changed the suffix to jsp instead of html and it all worked out.